# How to swap inside DIV data when up and down button press using js and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

I have working code.in which I have one timeline. and each event inside timeline is connected to each other.

Here is one delete button that removes the particular data. and there is another one which copies the data.
But I want when I click on up button and down button.

Like when I click on up button. it should swap the third element data to second data and second data to third data.
and same working on down button.
Here is working example code please see it.
And help will be appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#edit_button").click(function() {
    $("#slide").css("display", "none");
  })
  $("#slide section").attr("contenteditable", "true");
  var i = 1;
  $("section").each(function() {
    $(this).attr("id", i);
    $(this).append("<div class='deleteStyle'>" + "&#10006" + "</div>");
    $(this).append("<div class='deleteStyle2'>" + "&#10010" + "</div>");
    $(this).append("<div class='deleteStyle3'>" + "&#x2191" + "</div>");
    $(this).append("<div class='deleteStyle4'>" + "h" + "</div>");
    i++;
  });

  $("#slide").on('click', '.deleteStyle', function() {
    $(this).parent("section").remove()
  });
  $("#slide").on('click', '.deleteStyle2', function() {
    var ele = $(this).closest("section").clone(true);
    $(this).closest("section").after(ele);
  });
  $("#slide").on('click', '.deleteStyle4', function() {
    var currentData = $(this).parent().next().html();
    var currentString = "<section>" + currentData + "</section>";
    console.log(currentString)
    var abc1 = $(this).next().replaceWith(currentString);
    console.log(abc1)
  });
  $("#slide").on('click', '.deleteStyle3', function() {
    var previousData = $(this).parent().prev().html();
    var previousString = "<section>" + previousData + "</section>";
    console.log(previousString)
    var abc = $(this).prev().replaceWith(previousString);
    console.log(abc)
    // $(this).parent().remove().html();
    // $(this).closest("section").after(previousString);


    // $(this).closest("section").before(currentString);
    //    console.log(currentData);
    //    console.log(previousData);

  });


});
```

```css
div[type="timeline/slideshow"]>section,
div[type="timeline"]>section {
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 1;
  border-left: 4px solid #00BCD4;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  min-height: 130px;
  background-color: #b3e5fc2b;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 55px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  box-shadow: rgb(136, 136, 136) 3px 3px 1px;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
  -ms-animation: fadein 2s;
  -o-animation: fadein 2s;
  animation: fadein 2s;
}


/*div[type="timeline/slideshow"] > section:hover , div[type="timeline"] > section:hover {
 opacity:1;
} 
*/

div[type="timeline/slideshow"]::before,
div[type="timeline"]::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: .2rem;
  background: white;
  height: 55px;
}

div[type="timeline/slideshow"]>section::after,
div[type="timeline"]>section::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -56px;
  width: .2rem;
  background: grey;
  height: 54px;
}

div[type="timeline/slideshow"]>section>header,
div[type="timeline"]>section>header {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: cadetblue;
  transform: translate(16px, 23px);
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: arial;
  padding: 3px;
  position: relative;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  line-height: 31px;
}

div[type="timeline/slideshow"]>section>article,
div[type="timeline"]>section>article {
  transform: translate(12px, 14px);
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: arial;
  position: relative;
  padding: 9px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  line-height: 31px;
}

div[type="timeline"]>section:last-of-type::after {
  display: none;
}

div[type="slideshow"] {
  height: 471px;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
}

div[type="slideshow"]>section:not(.hideClass) {
  margin: auto;
  width: 900px;
  max-height: 265px;
  z-index: 100;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  border-left: 4px solid #00BCD4;
  min-height: 250px;
  background-color: #b3e5fc2b;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 55px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  top: 21.4%;
  left: 168px;
  box-shadow: rgb(136, 136, 136) 3px 3px 1px;
}

div[type="slideshow"]>section:not(.hideClass)>header {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: cadetblue;
  transform: translate(93px, 32px);
  font-size: 34px;
  font-family: arial;
  position: relative;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

div[type="slideshow"]>section:not(.hideClass)>article {
  transform: translate(87px, 39px);
  max-width: 800px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: arial;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}


/*.activeClass{    
 opacity: 1 !important;
}
*/

.hideClass {
  opacity: 0;
  min-height: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.hideClass header,
.hideClass article {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

div[type="timeline"] br {
  display: none;
}

.progressClass {
  height: 4px;
  display: none;
  top: 46px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: -1px;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.color_arrow {
  position: relative;
  top: 228px;
  color: #085153;
  left: 93px;
}

.color_arrows {
  position: relative;
  top: 228px;
  color: #085153;
  left: 94% !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  div[type="timeline/slideshow"]>section,
  div[type="timeline"]>section {
    width: 650px;
  }
  .color_arrow {
    left: -18px;
  }
  div[type="slideshow"]>section:not(.hideClass) {
    width: 640px;
    left: 14px;
  }
  .color_arrows {
    left: 99% !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  div[type="slideshow"]>section {
    width: 650px;
  }
  div[type="slideshow"]>section:not(.hideClass) {
    width: 640px;
    left: 18px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) and (max-width: 1299px) {
  div[type="slideshow"]>section:not(.hideClass) {
    width: 845px;
    left: 154px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  div[type="slideshow"]>section:not(.hideClass) {
    width: 698px;
    left: 136px;
  }
}

#slide {
  display: block;
}

.edit_timeline {
  margin: 4%;
}

.containers {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-style: arial;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 2%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

#modal_timeline {
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.deleteStyle {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  float: right;
  right: 12px;
  bottom: 80px;
  color: white;
}

.deleteStyle2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  float: right;
  right: 17px;
  bottom: 80px;
  color: white;
}

.deleteStyle3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  float: right;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 80px;
  color: white;
}

.deleteStyle4 {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  float: right;
  right: 24px;
  bottom: 80px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="containers">Click on Edit Timeline button to see the Timeline.</div>
<div class="demo">
  <div type="timeline" id="slide">
    <section>
      <header>Title One</header>
      <article>Content one</article>
    </section>
    <section>
      <header>Title Two</header>
      <article>Content one</article>
    </section>
    <section>
      <header>Title Three</header>
      <article>Content one</article>
    </section>
    <section>
      <header>Title Four</header>
      <article>Content one</article>
    </section>
  </div>

</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="modal_timeline" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Edit Timeline</button>
```

Comment: Looking for **keyup and keydown** events?

Comment: yes like that  swap the data

Comment: Can you make your code minimal yet complete ?

Comment: please don't focus on css please look at my js it very simple i get the both the data on console up and down events. how can i swap data.

Comment: i recommend you to refer this JSfiddle . https://jsfiddle.net/HarishSTOnline/ex984xL0/1/ 

I think this is what you're exactly want to do!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the jsfiddle for your referance. Here on mouse down and up key pressed item will be selected. 
     https://jsfiddle.net/webdev_sudhi/avudyb2t/3/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#edit_button").click(function() {
        $("#slide").css("display", "none");
    })
    $("#slide section").attr("contenteditable", "true");
    var i = 1;
    $("section").each(function() {
        $(this).attr("id", i);
        $(this).append("<div class='deleteStyle'>" + "&#10006" + "</div>");
        $(this).append("<div class='deleteStyle2'>" + "&#10010" + "</div>");
        $(this).append("<div class='deleteStyle3'>" + "&#x2191" + "</div>");
        $(this).append("<div class='deleteStyle4'>" + "h" + "</div>");
        i++;
    });

    $("#slide").on('click', '.deleteStyle', function() {
        $(this).parent("section").remove()
    });
    $("#slide").on('click', '.deleteStyle2', function() {
        var ele = $(this).closest("section").clone(true);
        $(this).closest("section").after(ele);
    });
    $("#slide").on('click', '.deleteStyle4', function() {
        var currentData = $(this).parent().next().html();
        var currentString = "<section>" + currentData + "</section>";
        console.log(currentString)
        var abc1 = $(this).next().replaceWith(currentString);
        console.log(abc1)
    });
    $("#slide").on('click', '.deleteStyle3', function() {

    //added new code here
        var previousData = $(this).parent().prev();

        $preTitle = $(previousData).find('header').text();
        $preContent = $(previousData).find('article').text();

        $(this).parent().find('header').text($preTitle);
        $(this).parent().find('article').text($preContent);
        //end here 
        
        var previousString = "<section>" + previousData + "</section>";
        console.log(previousString)
        var abc = $(this).prev().replaceWith(previousString);
        console.log(abc)
        // $(this).parent().remove().html();
        // $(this).closest("section").after(previousString);


        // $(this).closest("section").before(currentString);
        //    console.log(currentData);
        //    console.log(previousData);

    });


});
```

```css
div[type="timeline/slideshow"]>section,
div[type="timeline"]>section {
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 1;
  border-left: 4px solid #00BCD4;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  min-height: 130px;
  background-color: #b3e5fc2b;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 55px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  box-shadow: rgb(136, 136, 136) 3px 3px 1px;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
  -ms-animation: fadein 2s;
  -o-animation: fadein 2s;
  animation: fadein 2s;
}


/*div[type="timeline/slideshow"] > section:hover , div[type="timeline"] > section:hover {
 opacity:1;
} 
*/

div[type="timeline/slideshow"]::before,
div[type="timeline"]::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: .2rem;
  background: white;
  height: 55px;
}

div[type="timeline/slideshow"]>section::after,
div[type="timeline"]>section::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -56px;
  width: .2rem;
  background: grey;
  height: 54px;
}

div[type="timeline/slideshow"]>section>header,
div[type="timeline"]>section>header {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: cadetblue;
  transform: translate(16px, 23px);
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: arial;
  padding: 3px;
  position: relative;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  line-height: 31px;
}

div[type="timeline/slideshow"]>section>article,
div[type="timeline"]>section>article {
  transform: translate(12px, 14px);
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: arial;
  position: relative;
  padding: 9px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  line-height: 31px;
}

div[type="timeline"]>section:last-of-type::after {
  display: none;
}

div[type="slideshow"] {
  height: 471px;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
}

div[type="slideshow"]>section:not(.hideClass) {
  margin: auto;
  width: 900px;
  max-height: 265px;
  z-index: 100;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  border-left: 4px solid #00BCD4;
  min-height: 250px;
  background-color: #b3e5fc2b;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 55px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  top: 21.4%;
  left: 168px;
  box-shadow: rgb(136, 136, 136) 3px 3px 1px;
}

div[type="slideshow"]>section:not(.hideClass)>header {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: cadetblue;
  transform: translate(93px, 32px);
  font-size: 34px;
  font-family: arial;
  position: relative;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

div[type="slideshow"]>section:not(.hideClass)>article {
  transform: translate(87px, 39px);
  max-width: 800px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: arial;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}


/*.activeClass{    
 opacity: 1 !important;
}
*/

.hideClass {
  opacity: 0;
  min-height: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.hideClass header,
.hideClass article {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

div[type="timeline"] br {
  display: none;
}

.progressClass {
  height: 4px;
  display: none;
  top: 46px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: -1px;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.color_arrow {
  position: relative;
  top: 228px;
  color: #085153;
  left: 93px;
}

.color_arrows {
  position: relative;
  top: 228px;
  color: #085153;
  left: 94% !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  div[type="timeline/slideshow"]>section,
  div[type="timeline"]>section {
    width: 650px;
  }
  .color_arrow {
    left: -18px;
  }
  div[type="slideshow"]>section:not(.hideClass) {
    width: 640px;
    left: 14px;
  }
  .color_arrows {
    left: 99% !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  div[type="slideshow"]>section {
    width: 650px;
  }
  div[type="slideshow"]>section:not(.hideClass) {
    width: 640px;
    left: 18px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) and (max-width: 1299px) {
  div[type="slideshow"]>section:not(.hideClass) {
    width: 845px;
    left: 154px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  div[type="slideshow"]>section:not(.hideClass) {
    width: 698px;
    left: 136px;
  }
}

#slide {
  display: block;
}

.edit_timeline {
  margin: 4%;
}

.containers {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-style: arial;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 2%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

#modal_timeline {
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.deleteStyle {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  float: right;
  right: 12px;
  bottom: 80px;
  color: white;
}

.deleteStyle2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  float: right;
  right: 17px;
  bottom: 80px;
  color: white;
}

.deleteStyle3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  float: right;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 80px;
  color: white;
}

.deleteStyle4 {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  float: right;
  right: 24px;
  bottom: 80px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="containers">Click on Edit Timeline button to see the Timeline.</div>
<div class="demo">
  <div type="timeline" id="slide">
    <section>
      <header>Title One</header>
      <article>Content one</article>
    </section>
    <section>
      <header>Title Two</header>
      <article>Content one</article>
    </section>
    <section>
      <header>Title Three</header>
      <article>Content one</article>
    </section>
    <section>
      <header>Title Four</header>
      <article>Content one</article>
    </section>
  </div>

</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="modal_timeline" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Edit Timeline</button>
```

Comment: I don't understand your code sudhi. I think you not getting my point.

Comment: So you need to copy contents from previous box to new one when click on arrow button

Comment: Only title and content  will be copied or entire div will copy?

Comment: can you check the jsfiddle attached in answer

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to you script to solve the problem:

**Javascript:** I used just one event to determine when you click up or down, but i had to add a data attribute with the name of the direction of the buttons to find out which button makes the call.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#edit_button").click(function () {
                $("#slide").css("display", "none");
            })
            $("#slide section").attr("contenteditable", "true");
            var i = 1;
            $("section").each(function () {
                $(this).attr("id", i);
                $(this).append("<div class='deleteStyle'>" + "&#10006" + "</div>");
                $(this).append("<div class='deleteStyle2'>" + "&#10010" + "</div>");
                $(this).append("<div class='deleteStyle3' data-direction='up'>" + "&#x2191" + "</div>");
                $(this).append("<div class='deleteStyle4'  data-direction='down' >" + "h" + "</div>");
                i++;
            });

            $("#slide").on('click', '.deleteStyle', function () {
                $(this).parent("section").remove()
            });
            $("#slide").on('click', '.deleteStyle2', function () {
                var ele = $(this).closest("section").clone(true);
                $(this).closest("section").after(ele);
            });
            $("#slide").on('click', '.deleteStyle3, .deleteStyle4 ', function (e) {
                var direction = $(e.currentTarget).data().direction,
                    $currentSection = $(this).parent(),
                    $sectionToMove = direction === 'up' ? $(this).parent().prev() : $(this).parent().next(),
                    currentSectionData = $currentSection.html(),
                    sectionToMoveData = $sectionToMove.html();

                $currentSection.html(sectionToMoveData);
                $sectionToMove.html(currentSectionData);
            });
        });
```

```css
div[type="timeline/slideshow"]>section,
div[type="timeline"]>section {
  margin: auto;
  width: 500px;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 1;
  border-left: 4px solid #00BCD4;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  min-height: 130px;
  background-color: #b3e5fc2b;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 55px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  box-shadow: rgb(136, 136, 136) 3px 3px 1px;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 2s;
  -ms-animation: fadein 2s;
  -o-animation: fadein 2s;
  animation: fadein 2s;
}


/*div[type="timeline/slideshow"] > section:hover , div[type="timeline"] > section:hover {
 opacity:1;
} 
*/

div[type="timeline/slideshow"]::before,
div[type="timeline"]::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  width: .2rem;
  background: white;
  height: 55px;
}

div[type="timeline/slideshow"]>section::after,
div[type="timeline"]>section::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: -56px;
  width: .2rem;
  background: grey;
  height: 54px;
}

div[type="timeline/slideshow"]>section>header,
div[type="timeline"]>section>header {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: cadetblue;
  transform: translate(16px, 23px);
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: arial;
  padding: 3px;
  position: relative;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  line-height: 31px;
}

div[type="timeline/slideshow"]>section>article,
div[type="timeline"]>section>article {
  transform: translate(12px, 14px);
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: arial;
  position: relative;
  padding: 9px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  line-height: 31px;
}

div[type="timeline"]>section:last-of-type::after {
  display: none;
}

div[type="slideshow"] {
  height: 471px;
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
}

div[type="slideshow"]>section:not(.hideClass) {
  margin: auto;
  width: 900px;
  max-height: 265px;
  z-index: 100;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  border-left: 4px solid #00BCD4;
  min-height: 250px;
  background-color: #b3e5fc2b;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 55px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  top: 21.4%;
  left: 168px;
  box-shadow: rgb(136, 136, 136) 3px 3px 1px;
}

div[type="slideshow"]>section:not(.hideClass)>header {
  font-weight: 600;
  color: cadetblue;
  transform: translate(93px, 32px);
  font-size: 34px;
  font-family: arial;
  position: relative;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

div[type="slideshow"]>section:not(.hideClass)>article {
  transform: translate(87px, 39px);
  max-width: 800px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: arial;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}


/*.activeClass{    
 opacity: 1 !important;
}
*/

.hideClass {
  opacity: 0;
  min-height: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}

.hideClass header,
.hideClass article {
  display: none;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

div[type="timeline"] br {
  display: none;
}

.progressClass {
  height: 4px;
  display: none;
  top: 46px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: -1px;
  margin-top: -1px;
}

.color_arrow {
  position: relative;
  top: 228px;
  color: #085153;
  left: 93px;
}

.color_arrows {
  position: relative;
  top: 228px;
  color: #085153;
  left: 94% !important;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  div[type="timeline/slideshow"]>section,
  div[type="timeline"]>section {
    width: 650px;
  }
  .color_arrow {
    left: -18px;
  }
  div[type="slideshow"]>section:not(.hideClass) {
    width: 640px;
    left: 14px;
  }
  .color_arrows {
    left: 99% !important;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  div[type="slideshow"]>section {
    width: 650px;
  }
  div[type="slideshow"]>section:not(.hideClass) {
    width: 640px;
    left: 18px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1201px) and (max-width: 1299px) {
  div[type="slideshow"]>section:not(.hideClass) {
    width: 845px;
    left: 154px;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
  div[type="slideshow"]>section:not(.hideClass) {
    width: 698px;
    left: 136px;
  }
}

#slide {
  display: block;
}

.edit_timeline {
  margin: 4%;
}

.containers {
  font-weight: 800;
  font-style: arial;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 2%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

#modal_timeline {
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.deleteStyle {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  float: right;
  right: 12px;
  bottom: 80px;
  color: white;
}

.deleteStyle2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  float: right;
  right: 17px;
  bottom: 80px;
  color: white;
}

.deleteStyle3 {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  float: right;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 80px;
  color: white;
}

.deleteStyle4 {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: cadetblue;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  float: right;
  right: 24px;
  bottom: 80px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="containers">Click on Edit Timeline button to see the Timeline.</div>
<div class="demo">
  <div type="timeline" id="slide">
    <section>
      <header>Title One</header>
      <article>Content one</article>
    </section>
    <section>
      <header>Title Two</header>
      <article>Content one</article>
    </section>
    <section>
      <header>Title Three</header>
      <article>Content one</article>
    </section>
    <section>
      <header>Title Four</header>
      <article>Content one</article>
    </section>
  </div>

</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="modal_timeline" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Edit Timeline</button>
```